# JaCoCo fails with "initializationError FAILED"

Tags: jacoco, android-sdk-tools

PS D:\Projects\MyApp> ./gradlew jacocoCoverage
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Task :myLibModule:testDebugUnitTest

com.example.sheets.BottomSheetServiceTest > initializationError FAILED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at RobolectricTestRunner.java:260
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at DefaultSdkPicker.java:118

1 test completed, 1 failed

> Task :myLibModule:testDebugUnitTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.#

And the Report:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to configure com.example.sheets.BottomSheetServiceTest.showBottomSheetWithOrientationChange: Package targetSdkVersion=32 > maxSdkVersion=31
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getChildren(RobolectricTestRunner.java:260)
```

JaCoCo version 0.8.7

And the build.gradle for `:myLibModule`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 32
    buildToolsVersion = "32.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(32)
        #..
```

Comment: Hey @Ralf Wickum any luck?

Comment: Nope, still do not use Jacoco, since no change and also no support